# A positive semidefinite$\Rightarrow A = BB^T$ efficiently computable?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Given any symmetric, positive semidefinite Matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, is it possible to efficiently compute a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $A = B^\top B$?

In particular, I wonder if it is possible to compute such a decomposition in polynomial time.

Note: By Lemma 1.1 in [Higham 1990](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/1193/01/covered/MIMS_ep2008_56.pdf), the matrix $B$ can chosen as an upper triangular.

Comment: Yes, look up Cholesky decompositions. Which takes $\frac{1}{3}n^3$ flops in general.

Comment: @NigelOvermars Does ordinary Cholesky work with semidefiniteness? I know that Matlab's and numpy's Cholesky decomposition functions blow up in your face if the problem isn't strictly positive definite. For example, in Matlab: >> chol([1 -1;-1 1])
Error using chol
Matrix must be positive definite.

Comment: @Ian I am afraid that I missed the semidefinite part. Looking it up in my books I fear that it is not possible, although we can make a $LDL^T$ decomposition.

Comment: In MATLAB, you should use `ldl` instead of `chol` if your matrix is not positive definite.